# How to delete the element (loading page + css animation 100%)?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, animation

How can I tell p js and jQuery
if @keyframes 100% ???

If @keyframes for the element == 100%, do something specific

My problem is I have an element on the page ,, I want to delete the element when the page loads, and if the animation is done in CSS

Meaning I do not want him to delete the element when the page loads. I just want to delete the element when the page is complete + animation 100%

The element is span (load-span)

HTML :

```
 <a href="#">
 <div class="back-move">
     <span class="load-span"></span>
     <div class="play-move"><span></span></div>
 </div>
 <p>GG img</p>
```

CSS:

```
    .load-span {
    position: absolute;
    background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, transparent, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8), transparent);
    width:40px;
    height: 100%;
    top: -50%;
    left: 100%;
    animation: load-span 1s;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    transform: translate(15px, 0px) skewX(35deg);
}

@keyframes load-span {
    100%{ top: 100%;left: -100%;}
}
```

Also I have tried :

```
$(window).on("load", function () {
 $('.load-span').on("animationend", function(){
    $(this).remove();
});
})
```

But it didn't work ):

Answer (score 1):

You can simply remove the `animation-iteration-count: infinite;` and this below code will work.

```js
$(window).on("load", function () {
 $('.load-span').on("animationend", function(){
console.log('fdfdf');
    $(this).remove();
});
})
```

```css
.load-span {
    position: absolute;
    background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, transparent, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8), transparent);
    width:40px;
    height: 100%;
    top: -50%;
    left: 100%;
    animation: load-span 1s;
   
    transform: translate(15px, 0px) skewX(35deg);
}

@keyframes load-span {
    100%{ top: 100%;left: -100%;}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#">
 <div class="back-move">
     <span class="load-span"></span>
     <div class="play-move"><span></span></div>
 </div>
 <p>GG img</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason your above snippet doesn't work is because your `animationend` listener is not being called as you've set the `animation-iteration-count` to `infinite`, which tells the browser that the animation is never ending.

There are two tricks you can use to solve this,

1.Get rid of `infinite` from the iteration count and set it to `1`, then your code snippet would work

```
$(window).on("load", function () {
    $('.load-span').on("animationend", function(){
        $(this).remove();
    });
})
```

2.If you're using some sort of inifinite loader, you could use a timer, as your animation duration is `1s`, you can create a setTimeout callback, that checks whether the page has fully loaded or not.

```
setTimeout(function(){
  // Check whether page has loaded or not
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

**You were close with this. So instead of this:**

```
$(window).on("load", function () {
  $('.load-span').on("animationend", function(){
  $(this).remove();
```

});
})

**You can try this:**
Use  **webkitAnimationEnd** along with **animationend**

```
    $(window).on("load", function () {
  $('.load-span').on("animationend webkitAnimationEnd", function(){
  $(this).remove();
```

});
})

Hope this works!